# C# dynamic table creation : display table data in aspx page using linq query in a wcf service

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm a C# newbie_and in programming in general_ and in a previous question [C# return linq result as a list from a wcf service method then use it in aspx web forms page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661548/c-sharp-return-linq-result-as-a-list-from-a-wcf-service-method-then-use-it-in-as) , I managed to return a row from a table and display the result in labels in my apx web forms page. Now I want to display the whole table-> an unknown number of rows. I edited my code and I was almost successful. The problem is that  the table that I get, **instead of the four different rows that my table contains, displays the first one four times**. I check again and again but I can't find the error nor some friends. Here is my code:

**staffPanel.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        displayClients_Ref.IdisplayClientsSrvcClient dcClient = new displayClients_Ref.IdisplayClientsSrvcClient();

        List<string> allClients = new List<string>(dcClient.displayClients());

        foreach (string row in allClients)
        {
            int size = 0;

            string client = allClients.FirstOrDefault();
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(client))
            {
                // record cannot be found
            }
            else
            {
                string[] columns = client.Split(';');
                size = columns.Length;


                TableRow tr = new TableRow();
                allClients_tbl.Rows.Add(tr);

                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                {
                    TableCell tc = new TableCell();
                    tc.Text = columns[i];
                    tr.Cells.Add(tc);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**displayClient.svc.cs**

```
 public List<string> displayClients()
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        try
        {

            using (paragon_db_Models.clients_Entity context = new paragon_db_Models.clients_Entity())
            {

                var query = from cl in context.clients
                            select cl;

                foreach (var c in query)
                {
                    string row = c.user_account_id + ";" + c.client_name + ";" + c.client_surname + ";" + c.business_name + ";" + c.client_address + ";" + c.postal_code + ";" + c.telephone_number + ";" + c.fax + ";" + c.email + ";" + c.fiscal_code + ";" + c.public_fiscal_service;
                    result.Add(row);
                }

            }
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return result;
        }
    }
```

If it is a simple, stupid little mistake that I cannot see I will remove the question. I'm open to suggestions and comments concerning a different way of doing this.

Comment: I think here is bug in this line - `string client = allClients.FirstOrDefault();`. You have already use for loop then why you use this line ??? It'll always return first record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need

```
string client = allClients.FirstOrDefault();
```

You are already getting the info you want with "row" in

```
foreach (string row in allClients)
```

Replace your "client" instances with "row". FirstOrDefault would always get the first object or null.

Comment: thank you! Now what should I do, remove or leave this question?